# How to run django localhost on another system in same private network

Tags: python, django, server, web-hosting

I am using django for my project. Now I want to access my project. Both my system and the another one are in the same private network. I am using VPN to connect to the network. How can I access http://localhost:8000 from another system?

What all I did:

1. `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`
2. `DEBUG = False`
3. `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
4. Using my IP (say 192.168.x.y) from another system to access the page, but no use - I still couldn't access the page. (I can access the page http://192.168.x.y:8000/home from the browser of the same system though)

My main motive is to launch the application and to be able to use it from a system - **both server and client machine are in same private network** connected either by VPN or LAN

Comment: `runserver` is for development only. If you want to use it on a server read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/ for a proper setup.

Comment: You may need to allow inbound traffic for the port 8000.

Comment: Nothing worked.. How to configure django in Apache server?

Answer (score 1):

Use IP with port number - 192.168.x.y:`port`
. It should work.

If not, check your application is listening on the port using command `lsof -i` on your application machine.

Answer (score 0):

mention your ip in ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py file like: ALLOWED_HOSTS=['192.168.x.y','localhost']

then run:

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:portnumber

then you can access your ip at any local machine